# Why do my posts look like they are in "admin editing mode"?

Tags: admin-bar

I have created a wordpress blog. But when I on my created website and click on a link that leads to one of my posts, I do get to that post, but with the following problem:

At the top I see this grey "wordpress option bar" with the wordpress simbol, "Costumize", "Howdy Admin" etc.  Like I would go on the post as an admin.  But I just want to visit the post "normally" like a normal user. How do I make the post look "normal"?  (how do you call this "Not normal" mode?

It seems to me it has something to do that the link to the post is also really weird: http://box5466.temp.domains/~eternbf8/the-prospect-of-an-eternal-blissful-life/

Shouldn't that link be something like https://my-domain-name/the-prospect-of-an-eternal-blissful-life ?

Does this have something to do with the "WordPress Address (URL)" or "Site Adress (URL)" in the general settings? (right now they are both set to http://box5466.temp.domains/~eternbf8 ) I think that wasn't always the case.

Any buzz words that help me google this problem (or just links where the problem is descirbed) are already helpful to me! I don't really know how to proceed in solving this. I am a newbie to wordpress.
Thanks!

[image: See that grey bar at the top? how do I get rid of it? and why is the url so weird?]

Comment: The bar at the top is the [Toolbar](https://codex.wordpress.org/Toolbar) aka Admin Bar. It's normal to see this when you're logged in. You can view the post as a regular (logged out) user by using a private browsing window. Your URL probably looks funky because it seems that you're using a special preview domain provided by your hosting provider. Does the site work if you replace `http://box5466.temp.domains/~eternbf8/` with your real domain name? The site settings should use the real domain. More on changing the site URL [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grey bar at the top of your site is the WordPress Toolbar or Admin Bar. This is displayed, by default, for logged in users and is completely normal behaviour.

If your "WordPress Address (URL)" or "Site Adress (URL)" is set to http://box5466.temp.domains/~eternbf8 then this is the URL that will be used for all pages and links on your site - it's a temporary URL/domain name from your web hosting. You'll need to change the "WordPress Address (URL)" or "Site Adress (URL)" to your real domain name if you want the site to work from there.

As per the link that Dave provided above in his comment, you can read more about changing the site URL there - https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

**Note** Both settings should include the http:// part and should not have a slash "/" at the end.

Comment: Thanks!  Sorry for the kind of stupid question..  I was just confused because the admin bar didn't show earlier and I did not know what to google to get rid of it.